# Open folder in vscode using autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to open a specific folder with VScode when I press a button. Can I bind this to a script with autohotkey?
I'm using autohotkey V1

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What button are you pressing?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following hotkey code, replace C:\Deforum\ with the path you would like to open in VSCode, be sure to use the trailing slash:

```
vscodepath := "C:\Users\" . A_UserName . "\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe C:\Deforum\"

^!1::
Run % vscodepath
return
```